# How to pool a Java object in WebSphere Application Server 7.0?

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7, pool

I have simple class object which I want to pool in `WebSphere Application Server 7.0`.

My Java class looks like this:

```
SimpleBean
{
    String str1;
    String str2;

    SimpleBean()
    {str1="This is str1";}

    public void setStr1(String str1)
    {this.str1 = str1;}

    public void setStr2(String str2)
    {this.str2 = str2;}

    public String getStr1()
    {return str1;}

    public String getStr2()
    {return str2;}
}
```

How do I pool `SimpleBean` in WAS 7.0? I saw that there's an `Object pool managers` in WAS but I don't know if the pooling should be setup up there. Also I don't know how to use it.

Comment: I donot understand what you want to do. What do you mean by pool SimpleBean ??

Comment: @VKSingla: I want to pool a simple Java class that I've written. The name of my class is `SimpleBean.java`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Object pools](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/welc6tech_objp_adm.html) topic in the WebSphere Application Server 7.0 InfoCenter for more information on developing and configuring.

Comment: Hi, bkail! Thanks! I tried that tutorial but it gives me an error when I run the code, `arrayListPool = opm.getPool(ArrayList.class);`. The error is: `com.ibm.ws.objectpool.ObjectPoolImpl incompatible with com.ibm.security.krb5.wss.util.ObjectPool`. Would you know a more detailed tutorial? Also, how did WebSphere know that it will be pooling for `ArrayList` and `String`? Is there no need for the user to specify what object he wishes to pool in WAS?

Comment: That error means that your source code is importing the wrong ObjectPool; update your code to import com.ibm.websphere.objectpool.ObjectPool instead.  Object pools are not a popular programming model extension, so I am aware of their existence but have no experience with using them, sorry.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to make it work. As you have said, the problem is with the package I imported. Just a clarification though, are you really referring to `com.ibm.websphere.objectpool.ObjectPool'? Because I can't find it. The package I imported is `com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.pool.ObjectPool` and I was able to access the object pool already. Also, what do you mean with object pools are not a popular programming model extension? Are you referring to Websphere's pooling or object pooling in general?

Comment: Because I was also able to pool in Spring, an application framework. I'm just checking how the pooling in WebSphere works. Should I use rather use Spring's pooling or Websphere's pooling? Thanks again!

Comment: Oops, yes, I'm not sure where I got the bogus package name from; sorry. I don't have experience with either pooling implementation, so I would recommend using the one that's easiest and has the features you need.